# In an Ionic 2 app, how can I use Angular 2's long-stack-trace-zone.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I really want to use Angular 2’s zone.js long-stack-trace-zone.js with my application during development. I can’t figure out how to do this. I’ve looked at the example which uses it in the Angular GitHub here: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/example/basic.html

But it seems that I would need to have access to the bootstrapping to do that. Ionic seems to have it’s own bootstrap function. I’m not sure how to tackle this. Any hints would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Julie

Comment: What version of Ionic 2 are you using?  The latest, beta.11, provides the `ionicBootstrap()` function which is essentially identical to the angular bootstrap function - http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/ionicBootstrap/

Comment: I'm using Ionic 2rc0